# R: combining entries of strings of different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, substring, subset, combinations

I am using R and i have a dataframe with two columns which have the following appearance:

```
+-----+-------+
|  IDs| Names |
+-----+-------+
| 1,2 | a,b   |
|3,4,5| c,d,e |
|  .  | .     |
+-----+-------+
```

I want as result the following dataframe:

```
+-----+-------+
|  IDs| Names |
+-----+-------+
|  1  | a     |
|  2  | b     |
|  3  | c     |
|  4  | d     |
|  5  | e     |
+-----+-------+
```

Any guess ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, IDs, Names)
#    IDs Names
#1   1     a
#2   2     b
#3   3     c
#4   4     d
#5   5     e
```

---

Or with `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, c("IDs", "Names"), ",", "long")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(IDs = c('1,2', '3,4,5'), Names = c('a,b', 'c,d,e'), 
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: I have just updated the question because i forgot to mention that rows may have different entries. When i use separate_rows it tells me that i have no common size.

Comment: @LorenzoCapelli Your new example still works for me.  Please check my update

Comment: Yes, you are right, i had a problem with the dataframe. Sometimes, i have the names with a " ' " and it gives me some problems when i split the entries setting " ; " as separator. Thank you very much for the answer !

Comment: @LorenzoCapelli. There is a `sep` argument in `separate_rows` where you can correctly specify a regex to match only the relevant delimiters i.e. `sep=";"` because by default it assumes all the characters that are not alphanumeric as `sep` If you check `?separate_rows` `sep = "[^[:alnum:].]+"`

Answer (score 1):

@akrun's solution is great, but here's an alternative without any additional libraries:

```
df1 <- data.frame(IDs = c('1,2', '3,4,5'), Names = c('a,b', 'c,d,e'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(sapply(sapply(df1, paste, collapse = ','), strsplit, ','))
```

If you want to avoid it all on one line/how it works:

```
step_1 <- sapply(df1, paste, collapse = ',') # squish the columns together into a single string
step_2 <- sapply(step_1, strsplit, ',') # split the new strings into vectors
df2 <- data.frame(step_2) # create a new df from those vectors
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment !